# Show default page template for product categories in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm having a problem with WooCommerce / Wordpress templates. I used to have everything working.

I have this code in my `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'wpse138858_woocommerce_category_archive_template' );
function wpse138858_woocommerce_category_archive_template( $original_template ) {
    if ( is_product_category() ) {
        return get_template_directory().'/woocommerce/archive-product.php';
    } else {
        return $original_template;
    }
}
```

This code chose my custom archive template for product categories and shop the main page. Suddenly, it's not working anymore. It seems like WordPress cannot use custom files from `wp-content/themes/mytheme/woocommerce` anymore. Single product page and product categories use `page.php` for some reason. I fixed an issue with single product page by creating file single-product.php on my theme folder. This works okay but I can't do the same with Woocommerce archive pages.

All archive pages uses page.php. They don't have pageId and I print out `var_dump(is_product_category());` on some product category page, result is false.

Is there any way to force product categories to use `archive-product.php` template? How is it possible that category (archive) page uses `page.php` template?

Comment: Hey, Has this issue cropped up since the 3.3.0 update? I'm having the same issue and believe it is related to the FIX - Fix – Added woocommerce_output_product_categories to replace woocommerce_product_subcategories function to prevent outdated theme template files from outputting categories on the shop and category pages in err.

Comment: @jlow did you ever figure this out?—i am having the same issue and spent a couple of hours the other night trying every possible solution i could find, but no matter what, for whatever reason, it just keeps defaulting back to the `page.php` template. i even double checked all of my conditionals to make sure they were executing with the correct values, and i am certain they are.

Answer (score 3):

Add `add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );` in your theme `functions.php` file. After this all WooCommerce templates will work as expected ( provided that the structure of the templates is correct ).